# Sequential composition in vertx from list of items

Tags: java, vert.x

I am trying to execute sequential composition of futures in Vertx Java. 
I have an array (it could also be a list with unknown number) that I need to loop through and call the db server via reactive mysql (that is on vertx)
This is the code:

    `DbTransferRecord[] arrayData = new DbTransferRecord[4];`

```
arrayData[0].setID(1);
arrayData[0].setName("John");
arrayData[0].setLastName("Smith");
arrayData[1].setID(2);
arrayData[1].setName("Johnas");
arrayData[1].setLastName("Smith");


int arrayDataLength = arrayData.length;

for (int i = 0; i < arrayDataLength; i++) {
dbSaveData(arrayData[i].getId(), arrayData[i].getName(). arrayData[i].getLastName());
}


public Future<dbDataResponse> dbSaveData (id, name, lastName) throws Exception{
Promise<dbDataResponse> = Promise.promise();
....
return promise.future();
}
```

I need to chain every call from dbSaveData sequentially,so if one of the calls to db fails, a handler should be called to clean up (rollback) the data.
The documentation is very limited. I could  not find how to create sequential composition from list, and I could not understand it enough from the information I found on stackoverflow and the internet.
Thank you.

Comment: You can **compose or setHandler** on dbSaveData call and do the needful after checking if the DB save of success or failure.

Comment: @AshutoshSharma how exactly?